# null values passed when passing ITestContext attribute value to onTestStart method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I want to pass  the variables that I set using ITestContext   to onTestStart

```
   public void login(ITestContext Test){
        Test.setAttribute("nodeName","05 test");
        Test.setAttribute("nodeDetails","05 This belongs to regresion test");
   }
```

I used below code but only null values get printed.

```
 @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        //get the node name
        String node= (String) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("nodeName");
        String nodeDetails= (String) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("nodeDetails");
        System.out.println("onTestStart node is "+node);
        System.out.println("onTestStart nodeDetails is* "+nodeDetails);
}
```

However,  I did notice that when  I put it to   onTestSuccess method.

My original requirement is to pass  the node name and node details for extent's report node creation in **onTestStart method**. Kindly help.

```
test = report.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName()).createNode(node).pass(nodeDetails);
```

Comment: Is the `login` method the `@Test` method?

Comment: yes  Gautham , it's  @Test
    private void login(){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> onStart: This method is invoked before any test method gets executed.
> You can use this to set your extra attributes if you need to.
>
> onTestStart: This method is invoked before any tests method is
> invoked. This can be used to indicate that the particular test method
> has been started.

```
   @Override
   public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

        context.setAttribute("nodeName","05 test");
        context.setAttribute("nodeDetails","05 This belongs to regresion test");
   }
```

=== Edited

If you want to add some attributes to the ITestContext before (ALL Tests are run), then use @BeforeTest

Use @BeforeTest, this will be run once before all other tests are run.

```
   @BeforeTest
   public void setData(ITestContext context)
   {
      context.setAttribute("nodeName","05 test");
   }
```

If you want to do some logic that is supposed to run before (EACH) test method, then use

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(ItestContext testContext) {
    // Do testContext related processing
}
```

If neither of the above, and you want to pass custom data to each @Test case, then DataProvider is what you are looking for.

An example:

```
    @DataProvider(name = "node-05-provider")
    public Object[][] dataProvider(){
            return new Object[][]{
                {"node-05"}};
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="node-05-provider")
    public void search(String data){
     
         System.out.println(data); // "node-05"


    }
```

Comment: Sorry , I want to  set the attributes ,from my TestCase class using at Test, it worked for me when I  set them in BeforeClass
    private void setUp(ITestContext context)
    { However, I'm looking for a way to pass via in each @Test method if it's possible . Thank you.